# ngrx store not updated on another route until page is reloaded

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have an Angular 7 application where I am using ngrx. When I add a file object to my store I see the changes in the redux inspector but whenever I go to the route which displays the files I don't get the recently added file until I reload the browser. I have been trying to find out what causes this but haven't been able to so far.

Reducer:

```js
case FilesActionTypes.GET_FILES:
    return { ...state, loading: true };
case FilesActionTypes.GET_FILES_SUCCESS:
    return adapter.addAll(action.payload.data, state);
case FilesActionTypes.UPLOAD_FILE_SUCCESS:
      return adapter.addOne(action.payload.file, { ...state, loading: false });
```

I am just using the default selectAll selector.
Selector:

```
export const selectAllFiles = createSelector(selectFilesState, selectAll);
```

This is my component where I display the files:

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  public id: string;
  public files$: Observable<any>;
  public user$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private filesStore: Store<FilesState>,
              private usersStore: Store<UsersState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.files$ = this.filesStore.select(selectAllFiles);
    this.user$ = this.usersStore.select(selectCurrentUser);
    this.usersStore.dispatch(new GetUserAction({ id: this.id, params: null }));
    this.filesStore.dispatch(new GetFilesAction({ query: { entityId: this.id, entityService: 'users' }}));
  }

}
```

and my template:

```html
 <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <div *ngFor="let file of files$ | async">
        <a [href]="['http://localhost:3030/files/'] + file._id" target="_blank">{{ file.name }}</a>
       </div>
 </ng-template>
```

If you need more code I can provide it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have narrowed down my problem a bit more.

I have a /users route and /users/:id route. If I add a file(from /users route) without going to the /users/:id route first then I can see the updated list of files when navigating to /users/:id route. But if I go to /users/:id route and back to /users and add a file and again going to my /users/:id I don't see the updated list of files until I reload the page.

Maybe this can help you help me.

Comment: is `localhost:3030`, the route of your application ? Or is it an another localhost ?

Comment: It’s another localhost. The files are displaying just fine on the other localhost which is a feathers js backend . My problem is listing them. I should have made that more clear in my description.

Comment: I can confirm that it is destroyed.

Comment: It's like the states are inconsistent between the routes when I have navigated to the route where UserComponent is used first. I did use the redux inspector and I am not getting the correct amount of file entities after navigating to /users/:id when I have added from /users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed parentheses
`<div *ngFor="let file of (files$ | async)">`

However, you could check if the data is there before doing the ngfor

```
 <ng-template ngbTabContent *ngIf="files$ | async as files">
   <div *ngFor="let file of files">
    <a [href]="['http://localhost:3030/files/'] + file._id" target="_blank">{{ file.name }}</a>
   </div>
 </ng-template>
```

Comment: This won't fix my problem. The problem is when I add one file from another route and go to the route where the list of these links are displayed I don't see the newly added link until I reload the page. My states are inconsistent between the two routes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was on the backend side.

Problem is solved. Have a nice day!